# .run file has no VFS data to start up

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded metasploit 64 bit version for linux (I have ubuntu 13.04 x64 installed). It comes as a .run file. As all of the tutorials say, I tried to install it as follows.

```
sudo chmod a+x metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

But I encountered the following error. I have tried many times, but same result in each attempt. I get the error message followed by a `%` prompt as follows.

```
application-specific initialization failed: 
  /home/djays/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run has no VFS data to start up
%
```

Then I tried to install it using `bash` command. It also gives another error.

```
metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run: metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run: cannot execute binary file
```

Can anybody give me a solution.

**Edit:**
   As some answers said in the internet, I checked whether downloaded .run file is corrupted or not downloaded completely, and then I redownloaded it about 4 times. But still get the same result. I checked whether gvfs is installed, and the latest version is installed in my machine.

Comment: Can you try `sudo ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run`?

Comment: @Alaa, thanks for the response. I tried it. I get the same result.

Comment: Check the size of the installer. This can happen if the download was not completed.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I checked it. It was 272.7MB. I downloaded it several times then but I got the same error. I am now downloading the latest one. It is bit smaller in size, 167MB.

Comment: Yeah I'm also downloading the 167 MB one, from Rapid7's website. The one that was giving you an error was the 272 MB one? Where'd you get it from?

Comment: @Alaa, Rinzwind. PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!!!!!!!!! I just downloaded the 32 bit version (still my OS is ubuntu 13.04 x64) And it worked perfectly. I followed the given steps and worked. My OS being 64 bit, how can the 32 bit installer work where 64bit installer fails. Do you have any idea? btw, I appreciate both of your responses. :)

Comment: It's probably a corrupted file. I just downloaded the 64-bit installer [from here](http://www.rapid7.com/products/metasploit/download.jsp) (scroll down and look for Metasploit Framework) and it works. It's around 170 MB and the md5 hash is `b36d8c7282f91e8bcb0138f2feb702cf`. Check yours and see if it matches (check the hash by `md5sum metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run`).

Comment: Well boys, save your goodies in an answer for the solved problem.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed 167MB 32bit Metasploit installer. Now I am downloading the 64bit one. It is also 167MB in size.

Comment: @Alaa, you were correct. Downloaded 64bit version again and tried. Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded both of them and they were both 167 MB. Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted when you can =).

Comment: Ok, I'll mark it after 2 days as it says :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely due to the bad downloaded file. I downloaded 32bit version of Metasploit and installed. Though initial step worked, starting metasploit fails because of the conflicting of rubygems. So, I uninstalled the 32bit Metasploit and installed newly downloaded 64bit Metasploit. It worked perfectly and Metasploit can be run without no error. All problems solved.